# Unable to click on elements when connecting the Appium to the real android device

Tags: android, appium

Environment

- Appium Version 1.4.16.1
- UIAutomatorviewer version 2.0
- Android version 6.0 (Nougat)

The application is developed with angular ionic2.
I am using uiautomatorviewer and i am able to identify all the elements in the screen. But when i run my script i am getting an error message says unable to locate the element.
Appium log

```
info:  [debug] Pushing appium bootstrap to device...
info:  [debug] executing cmd: E:\path\platform-tools\adb.exe -s ce041714c44ebd1802 push "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Appium\\node_modules\\appium\\build\\android_bootstrap\\AppiumBootstrap.jar" /data/local/tmp/
info:  [debug] Pushing settings apk to device...
info:  [debug] executing cmd: E:\path\platform-tools\adb.exe -s ce041714c44ebd1802 install "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\settings_apk\settings_apk-debug.apk"
info:  [debug] Pushing unlock helper app to device...
info:  [debug] executing cmd: E:\path\platform-tools\adb.exe -s ce041714c44ebd1802 install "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\unlock_apk\unlock_apk-debug.apk"
info:  Starting App
info:  [debug] Attempting to kill all 'uiautomator' processes
info:  [debug] Getting all processes with 'uiautomator'
info:  [debug] executing cmd: E:\path\platform-tools\adb.exe -s ce041714c44ebd1802 shell "ps"| grep uiautomator
info:  [debug] No matching processes found
info:  [debug] Running bootstrap
info:  [debug] spawning: E:\path\platform-tools\adb.exe -s ce041714c44ebd1802 shell uiautomator runtest AppiumBootstrap.jar -c io.appium.android.bootstrap.Bootstrap -e pkg io.ionic.starter -e disableAndroidWatchers false
info:  [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] Warning: This version of UI Automator is deprecated. New tests should be written using
info:  [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] UI Automator 2.0 which is available as part of the Android Testing Support Library.
info:  [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] See https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/uiautomator-testing.html
info:  [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] for more details.
info:  [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: numtests=1
info:  [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: stream=
info:  [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] io.appium.android.bootstrap.Bootstrap:
info:  [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: id=UiAutomatorTestRunner
info:  [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: test=testRunServer
info:  [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: class=io.appium.android.bootstrap.Bootstrap
info:  [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: current=1
info:  [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: 1
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Socket opened on port 4724
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Appium Socket Server Ready
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Loading json...
info:  [debug] Waking up device if it's not alive
info:  [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["wake",{}]
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Registered crash watchers.
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Client connected
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"wake","params":{}}
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: wake
info:  [debug] executing cmd: E:\path\platform-tools\adb.exe -s ce041714c44ebd1802 shell "dumpsys window"
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"status":0,"value":true}
info:  [debug] Screen already unlocked, continuing.
info:  [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["getDataDir",{}]
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"getDataDir","params":{}}
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: getDataDir
info:  [debug] dataDir set to: /data/local/tmp
info:  [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["compressedLayoutHierarchy",{"compressLayout":false}]
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"status":0,"value":"\/data\/local\/tmp"}
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"compressedLayoutHierarchy","params":{"compressLayout":false}}
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: compressedLayoutHierarchy
info:  [debug] Getting device API level
info:  [debug] executing cmd: E:\path\platform-tools\adb.exe -s ce041714c44ebd1802 shell "getprop ro.build.version.sdk"
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"status":0,"value":false}
info:  [debug] Device is at API Level 24
info:  [debug] executing cmd: E:\path\platform-tools\adb.exe -s ce041714c44ebd1802 shell "am start -S -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -f 0x10200000 -n io.ionic.starter/io.ionic.starter.MainActivity"
info:  [debug] Waiting for pkg "io.ionic.starter" and activity "io.ionic.starter.MainActivity" to be focused
info:  [debug] Getting focused package and activity
info:  [debug] executing cmd: E:\path\platform-tools\adb.exe -s ce041714c44ebd1802 shell "dumpsys window windows"
info:  [debug] executing cmd: E:\path\platform-tools\adb.exe -s ce041714c44ebd1802 shell "getprop ro.build.version.release"
info:  [debug] Device is at release version 7.0
info:  [debug] Device launched! Ready for commands
info:  [debug] Setting command timeout to the default of 60 secs
info:  [debug] Appium session started with sessionId 0212f982-e957-48b8-999d-033d5f62a6ce
info:  <-- POST /wd/hub/session 303 17850.686 ms - 74 
info:  --> GET /wd/hub/session/0212f982-e957-48b8-999d-033d5f62a6ce {}
info:  [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"platform":"LINUX","browserName":"Android","platformVersion":"7.0","webStorageEnabled":false,"takesScreenshot":true,"javascriptEnabled":true,"databaseEnabled":false,"networkConnectionEnabled":true,"locationContextEnabled":false,"warnings":{},"desired":{"appPackage":"io.ionic.starter","appActivity":"io.ionic.starter.MainActivity","automationName":"uiautomator2","browserName":"Android","platformName":"Android","version":"7.0","deviceName":"b133582d"},"appPackage":"io.ionic.starter","appActivity":"io.ionic.starter.MainActivity","automationName":"uiautomator2","platformName":"Android","version":"7.0","deviceName":"ce041714c44ebd1802"},"sessionId":"0212f982-e957-48b8-999d-033d5f62a6ce"}
info:  <-- GET /wd/hub/session/0212f982-e957-48b8-999d-033d5f62a6ce 200 1.986 ms - 711 {"status":0,"value":{"platform":"LINUX","browserName":"Android","platformVersion":"7.0","webStorageEnabled":false,"takesScreenshot":true,"javascriptEnabled":true,"databaseEnabled":false,"networkConnectionEnabled":true,"locationContextEnabled":false,"warnings":{},"desired":{"appPackage":"io.ionic.starter","appActivity":"io.ionic.starter.MainActivity","automationName":"uiautomator2","browserName":"Android","platformName":"Android","version":"7.0","deviceName":"b133582d"},"appPackage":"io.ionic.starter","appActivity":"io.ionic.starter.MainActivity","automationName":"uiautomator2","platformName":"Android","version":"7.0","deviceName":"ce041714c44ebd1802"},"sessionId":"0212f982-e957-48b8-999d-033d5f62a6ce"}
info:  --> POST /wd/hub/session/0212f982-e957-48b8-999d-033d5f62a6ce/timeouts {"type":"implicit","ms":30000}
info:  [debug] Set Android implicit wait to 30000ms
info:  [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":null,"sessionId":"0212f982-e957-48b8-999d-033d5f62a6ce"}
info:  <-- POST /wd/hub/session/0212f982-e957-48b8-999d-033d5f62a6ce/timeouts 200 1.988 ms - 76 {"status":0,"value":null,"sessionId":"0212f982-e957-48b8-999d-033d5f62a6ce"}
info:  --> POST /wd/hub/session/0212f982-e957-48b8-999d-033d5f62a6ce/elements {"using":"class name","value":"android.widget.EditText"}
info:  [debug] Waiting up to 30000ms for condition
info:  [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["find",{"strategy":"class name","selector":"android.widget.EditText","context":"","multiple":true}]
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"find","params":{"strategy":"class name","selector":"android.widget.EditText","context":"","multiple":true}}
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: find
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Finding android.widget.EditText using CLASS_NAME with the contextId:  multiple: true
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Using: UiSelector[CLASS=android.widget.EditText]
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] getElements selector:UiSelector[CLASS=android.widget.EditText]
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Element[] is null: (0)
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] getElements tmp selector:UiSelector[CLASS=android.widget.EditText, INSTANCE=0]
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Failed to locate element. Clearing Accessibility cache and retrying.
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Finding android.widget.EditText using CLASS_NAME with the contextId:  multiple: true
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Using: UiSelector[CLASS=android.widget.EditText]
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] getElements selector:UiSelector[CLASS=android.widget.EditText]
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Element[] is null: (0)
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] getElements tmp selector:UiSelector[CLASS=android.widget.EditText, INSTANCE=0]
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"status":0,"value":[]}
info:  [debug] Waited for 8590ms so far
info:  [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["find",{"strategy":"class name","selector":"android.widget.EditText","context":"","multiple":true}]
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"find","params":{"strategy":"class name","selector":"android.widget.EditText","context":"","multiple":true}}
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: find
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Finding android.widget.EditText using CLASS_NAME with the contextId:  multiple: true
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Using: UiSelector[CLASS=android.widget.EditText]
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] getElements selector:UiSelector[CLASS=android.widget.EditText]
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Element[] is null: (0)
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] getElements tmp selector:UiSelector[CLASS=android.widget.EditText, INSTANCE=0]
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Failed to locate element. Clearing Accessibility cache and retrying.
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Finding android.widget.EditText using CLASS_NAME with the contextId:  multiple: true
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Using: UiSelector[CLASS=android.widget.EditText]
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] getElements selector:UiSelector[CLASS=android.widget.EditText]
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Element[] is null: (0)
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] getElements tmp selector:UiSelector[CLASS=android.widget.EditText, INSTANCE=0]
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"status":0,"value":[]}
info:  [debug] Waited for 11641ms so far
info:  [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["find",{"strategy":"class name","selector":"android.widget.EditText","context":"","multiple":true}]
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"find","params":{"strategy":"class name","selector":"android.widget.EditText","context":"","multiple":true}}
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: find
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Finding android.widget.EditText using CLASS_NAME with the contextId:  multiple: true
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Using: UiSelector[CLASS=android.widget.EditText]
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] getElements selector:UiSelector[CLASS=android.widget.EditText]
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Element[] is null: (0)
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] getElements tmp selector:UiSelector[CLASS=android.widget.EditText, INSTANCE=0]
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Failed to locate element. Clearing Accessibility cache and retrying.
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Finding android.widget.EditText using CLASS_NAME with the contextId:  multiple: true
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Using: UiSelector[CLASS=android.widget.EditText]
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] getElements selector:UiSelector[CLASS=android.widget.EditText]
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Element[] is null: (0)
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] getElements tmp selector:UiSelector[CLASS=android.widget.EditText, INSTANCE=0]
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"status":0,"value":[]}
info:  [debug] Waited for 15447ms so far
info:  [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["find",{"strategy":"class name","selector":"android.widget.EditText","context":"","multiple":true}]
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"find","params":{"strategy":"class name","selector":"android.widget.EditText","context":"","multiple":true}}
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: find
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Finding android.widget.EditText using CLASS_NAME with the contextId:  multiple: true
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Using: UiSelector[CLASS=android.widget.EditText]
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] getElements selector:UiSelector[CLASS=android.widget.EditText]
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Element[] is null: (0)
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] getElements tmp selector:UiSelector[CLASS=android.widget.EditText, INSTANCE=0]
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Failed to locate element. Clearing Accessibility cache and retrying.
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Finding android.widget.EditText using CLASS_NAME with the contextId:  multiple: true
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Using: UiSelector[CLASS=android.widget.EditText]
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] getElements selector:UiSelector[CLASS=android.widget.EditText]
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Element[] is null: (0)
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] getElements tmp selector:UiSelector[CLASS=android.widget.EditText, INSTANCE=0]
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"status":0,"value":[]}
info:  [debug] Waited for 18506ms so far
info:  [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["find",{"strategy":"class name","selector":"android.widget.EditText","context":"","multiple":true}]
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"find","params":{"strategy":"class name","selector":"android.widget.EditText","context":"","multiple":true}}
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: find
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Finding android.widget.EditText using CLASS_NAME with the contextId:  multiple: true
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Using: UiSelector[CLASS=android.widget.EditText]
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] getElements selector:UiSelector[CLASS=android.widget.EditText]
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Element[] is null: (0)
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] getElements tmp selector:UiSelector[CLASS=android.widget.EditText, INSTANCE=0]
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Failed to locate element. Clearing Accessibility cache and retrying.
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Finding android.widget.EditText using CLASS_NAME with the contextId:  multiple: true
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Using: UiSelector[CLASS=android.widget.EditText]
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] getElements selector:UiSelector[CLASS=android.widget.EditText]
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Element[] is null: (0)
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] getElements tmp selector:UiSelector[CLASS=android.widget.EditText, INSTANCE=0]
info:  [debug] Waited for 26835ms so far
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"status":0,"value":[]}
info:  [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["find",{"strategy":"class name","selector":"android.widget.EditText","context":"","multiple":true}]
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"find","params":{"strategy":"class name","selector":"android.widget.EditText","context":"","multiple":true}}
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: find
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Finding android.widget.EditText using CLASS_NAME with the contextId:  multiple: true
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Using: UiSelector[CLASS=android.widget.EditText]
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] getElements selector:UiSelector[CLASS=android.widget.EditText]
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Element[] is null: (0)
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] getElements tmp selector:UiSelector[CLASS=android.widget.EditText, INSTANCE=0]
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Failed to locate element. Clearing Accessibility cache and retrying.
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Finding android.widget.EditText using CLASS_NAME with the contextId:  multiple: true
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Using: UiSelector[CLASS=android.widget.EditText]
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] getElements selector:UiSelector[CLASS=android.widget.EditText]
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Element[] is null: (0)
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] getElements tmp selector:UiSelector[CLASS=android.widget.EditText, INSTANCE=0]
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"status":0,"value":[]}
info:  [debug] Waited for 29877ms so far
info:  [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["find",{"strategy":"class name","selector":"android.widget.EditText","context":"","multiple":true}]
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"find","params":{"strategy":"class name","selector":"android.widget.EditText","context":"","multiple":true}}
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: find
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Finding android.widget.EditText using CLASS_NAME with the contextId:  multiple: true
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Using: UiSelector[CLASS=android.widget.EditText]
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] getElements selector:UiSelector[CLASS=android.widget.EditText]
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Element[] is null: (0)
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] getElements tmp selector:UiSelector[CLASS=android.widget.EditText, INSTANCE=0]
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Failed to locate element. Clearing Accessibility cache and retrying.
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Finding android.widget.EditText using CLASS_NAME with the contextId:  multiple: true
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Using: UiSelector[CLASS=android.widget.EditText]
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] getElements selector:UiSelector[CLASS=android.widget.EditText]
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Element[] is null: (0)
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] getElements tmp selector:UiSelector[CLASS=android.widget.EditText, INSTANCE=0]
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"status":0,"value":[]}
info:  [debug] Condition unmet after 32916ms. Timing out.
info:  [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":[],"sessionId":"0212f982-e957-48b8-999d-033d5f62a6ce"}
info:  <-- POST /wd/hub/session/0212f982-e957-48b8-999d-033d5f62a6ce/elements 200 32918.226 ms - 74 {"status":0,"value":[],"sessionId":"0212f982-e957-48b8-999d-033d5f62a6ce"}
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Emitting system alert message
info:  [debug] Emitting alert message...
info:  [debug] Didn't get a new command in 60 secs, shutting down...
info:  Shutting down appium session
info:  [debug] Pressing the HOME button
info:  [debug] executing cmd: E:\path\platform-tools\adb.exe -s ce041714c44ebd1802 shell "input keyevent 3"
info:  [debug] Stopping logcat capture
info:  [debug] Logcat terminated with code null, signal SIGTERM
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"shutdown"}
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type SHUTDOWN
info:  [debug] Sent shutdown command, waiting for UiAutomator to stop...
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"status":0,"value":"OK, shutting down"}
info:  [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Closed client connection
info:  [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: numtests=1
info:  [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: stream=.
info:  [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: id=UiAutomatorTestRunner
info:  [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: test=testRunServer
info:  [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: class=io.appium.android.bootstrap.Bootstrap
info:  [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: current=1
info:  [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: 0
info:  [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: stream=
info:  [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] Test results for WatcherResultPrinter=.
info:  [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] Time: 111.066
info:  [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] OK (1 test)
info:  [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: -1
info:  [debug] UiAutomator shut down normally
info:  [debug] Cleaning up android objects
info:  [debug] Cleaning up appium session
info:  [debug] We shut down because no new commands came in
```

script

```
package Appium;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;

public class Sample1 {


AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver;
    public void setup(){

    DesiredCapabilities dc = new DesiredCapabilities();
    dc.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME,"Android");
    dc.setCapability(CapabilityType.VERSION,"7.0");
    dc.setCapability("deviceName","b133582d");
    dc.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
    dc.setCapability("appPackage", "io.ionic.starter");
    dc.setCapability("appActivity", "io.ionic.starter.MainActivity");


    try {
        driver= new AppiumDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), dc);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    System.out.println("Session is created");
    }
    public void sendtext(){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(15000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        }
        System.out.println("before");
        WebDriverWait driverWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);


  driverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.className("android.widget.EditText")));


  System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.className("android.widget.EditText")).getText());
        System.out.println("After");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Sample1 sam = new Sample1();
    sam.setup();
    sam.sendtext();



}}
```

Comment: try to search with `driver.findElementByClassName("android.widget.EditText");` and use `visibilityOfElementLocated(MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator("android.widget.EditText"))`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will check and let you know the result